# How to surpress warnings in JAX-WS RI?

Tags: eclipse, jax-ws

I'm using the JAX-WS RI to communicate with a WebService. During using my client (which works great btw.) I get those annoying messages:

```
09.10.2011 20:24:11 com.sun.xml.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl freeze
WARNUNG: Input Action on WSDL operation insertXYZ and @Action on its associated Web Method insertXYZ did not match and will cause problems in dispatching the requests
09.10.2011 20:24:11 com.sun.xml.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl freeze
WARNUNG: Input Action on WSDL operation executeXYZ and @Action on its associated Web Method executeXYZ did not match and will cause problems in dispatching the requests
```

I'm using wsimport to generate my stubs, so I don't know why I get them. But that is not the point of my question (if someone has a tip, I'd be happy though ;-)).

My question is how to surpress those messages in my logger. I did not found anything how to configure the logging behaviour. I'm executing my client in Eclipse Galileo. The only thing I found is how to dump the whole message traffic but this setting won't help me ;-)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the Apache CXF implementation instead :-)

Comment: I get these with Apache CXF as well.